# Back key is not behaving as usual

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an app which has a main activity and a class. When I press the back button, it should close the app, but it does nothing: when I press the button, the button backlight goes on and it goes off. If I press it again, I just hear some sound feedback.

My app is constantly doing Bluetooth communication. Can Bluetooth override the normal behavior of the key?

I also have onPause and onResume.

Tried with onBackPressed, it never gets called:

```
    @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();
    Log.i ("INFO","BackKey pressed");
         }
```

BtComm class:

```
    //Enables Bluetooth if not enabled
public void enableBT(){
localAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
//If Bluetooth not enable then do it
if(localAdapter.isEnabled()==false){
    localAdapter.enable();
    while(!(localAdapter.isEnabled())){

    }
}

}

    //connect to both NXTs
    public  boolean connectToNXTs(){



//get the BluetoothDevice of the NXT
BluetoothDevice nxt_1 = localAdapter.getRemoteDevice(nxt1);
//try to connect to the nxt
try {
    socket_nxt1 = nxt_1.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        socket_nxt1.connect();

    success = true;

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.i("Bluetooth","Err: Device not found or cannot connect");
    success=false;


}
if (success) {
     Log.i("CONECTE","CONEXION EXITOSA");
}
return success;

}






public void writeMessage(byte[] msg) throws InterruptedException{
//BluetoothSocket connSock;




  //  connSock=socket_nxt1;

    try {

       // OutputStreamWriter out =new OutputStreamWriter(connSock.getOutputStream());
      // mmOutStream.write(msg);
       // out.flush();
        OutputStream outputStream = socket_nxt1.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(msg);
        Log.i("Excelente","COMANDO EXITOSO");



    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("PROBLEMA","ERROR DE DATOS");
    }
}


public byte [] readMessage(){
byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
Log.i("Excelente","Entre a readmessage");

    try {

        InputStream inputstream = socket_nxt1.getInputStream();         
        inputstream.read(buffer);
        //mmInStream.read(buffer);

        Log.i("Excelente","Lei los datos");

        for (int index = 0; index < buffer.length; index++){

             Log.i("RECIBIDO:", String.format("0x%20x", buffer[index]));

        }

        Log.i("Excelente","Recibi datos y los escribi");

        return buffer;


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("PROBLEMA","ERROR DE DATOS AL RECIBIR");
        return null;
    }


}

public void cancel() {
    try {
        //OutputStream outputStream = socket_nxt1.getOutputStream();
        socket_nxt1.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR","Unable to close");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this Bluetooth communication on the main thread?

Comment: I have 1 class and 1 activity, in the class I do all the bluetooth communication

Comment: Show the code of your bluetooth connection

Comment: If you aren't doing any threading, then the bluetooth communication is likely blocking or otherwise slowing down the main thread, preventing it from processing back button presses.

Comment: That may be the problem, in the main activity (on onResume) there is a loop which constantly writes and reads from bluetooth. Any ideas on how to do threading?

Comment: Yes, use an AsyncTask. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html